# Runnig tasks only when merging to master

Tags: go, circleci

I use the following config which works as expected, it run the command on each PR or merge to the master, Now I want to make some integration test which I want to run **only when merged to the master**, all the PR should remain the same (and run the following config as before). the nuance here is that for the integration test I need **other docker image and different run command to execute** (which should execute only when merging to the master), is it possible to do it with CircleCI ?

```
# Golang CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      # specify the version
      - image: circleci/golang:1.11
    working_directory: /go/src/sbr
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: go version
      - run: go env
      - run: go get -v -t -d ./...
      - run: go test -v ./...
```

I try to add another docker image under the existing one but I got error

**update:**

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/golang:1.11
    working_directory: /go/src/sbr
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: go version
      - run: go env
      - run: go get -v -t -d ./...
      - run: go test -v ./...

  test-integration:
    docker:
      - image: other-image

workflows:
  version: 2
  builds:
    jobs:
      - build

  integration-test:
    jobs:
      - test-integration:
          requires:
            - build
          filters:
            branches:
              only: master
```

The issue here that I got error when adding to the second workflow the `require`

```
  requires:
    - build
```

I want that **before** the test `test-integration` it will also run the `build` job as per-requiste . what im doing wrong ?

*The error is:*

```
requires job \"build\" but \"build\" is not part of this workflow.
# At least one job in the workflow must have no dependencies.
# The following jobs are unreachable: integration
# 
# -------

# Don't rerun this job. Rerunning will have no effect.
false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration has a single job named `build` and no workflows. It sounds like what you want is to run a second job for integration tests, and to have the second job only run when the branch is master. To accomplish both of those you would use a workflow with two jobs.

See https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#workflows

An example of what that might look like:

```
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
     - image: circleci/golang:1.11
    ...

  test-integration:
    docker:
      - image: other-image
    ...

workflows:
  version: 2
  workflow-name:
    jobs: 
      - build
      - test-integration:
          filters:
            branches:
              only: master
```

Comment: Thank you very much, 1+, now the issue is that the jobs running on the master, should I create another workflow for all the PR branches ? if there is any example it will be great

Comment: I look at the docs and its a bit confusing. what i need that for each `PR` the `build job` will run and for merge to the master the `build and test-integration` will be executed

Comment: My example would do what you want. You don't need two workflows. You want a single workflow, where one of the jobs only runs on master.  If you want to use two workflows you need to add `build` to the list of jobs in the second one.

Comment: Thanks, im closing the question, it will be great if you can add example (update your answer)  of what you mean.... thanks a  lot